# Displaying div content in the same position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with below script it shows different div content when clicking on buttons. The problem is whenever I click on button the content reloads and brings me back top of the page. Can someone please tell me what I should do to stay 'in the same place' and just reload div content ?

---

edited: Thank you very much ! The solution below worked perfectly. I just wanted to ask if there is any simple way to change styles for the link which i currently chosen(displaying content) ?

You can check a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/PZnSb/6/

```
<div class="new_member_box">
  <a href="#" class="question1">
    <h4>Vision</h4>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="new_member_box">
  <a href="#" class="question2">
    <h4>History</h4>
  </a>
</div>

</div>
<div class="clear" class="question"></div>
<div id="answer1">
  1
</div>

<div id="answer2">
  2
</div>
<div class="new_member_box_display" id="question">
  Text will appear here when one of the tabs above is clicked
</div>


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.question1').click(function() {
      $('.new_member_box_display').html($('#answer1').html());
    }) $('.question2').click(function() {
      $('.new_member_box_display').html($('#answer2').html());
    })
  }); //end of ready
```

Comment: Is this working better for you http://jsfiddle.net/PZnSb/142/? also rewrote a bit of your code so its more dynamic

Comment: I think its working fine, check your fiddle

Comment: your code is ok, just loose the href=# and change the `<a>` tag for the button one...

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thank you it work fine, I just wonder if there is fast way of adding styles (color) for currently opened link ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `#` in the href with `javascript:void`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.question1').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').html($('#answer1').html());
  });

  $('.question2').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').html($('#answer2').html());
  });

  $('.question3').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').html($('#answer3').html());
  });

  $('.question4').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').html($('#answer4').html());
  });
 
});//end of ready
```

```css
.new_member_box_display{
  min-height: 300px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #e6ebe4; 
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 25px 0px 10px 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


.content_areas_left_textbody{
  font-family: calibri;
  margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
  height: auto;
}

#answer1, #answer2, #answer3, #answer4{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new_member_box">
  <a href="javascript:void" class="question1">
    <h4>Vision</h4>
  </a>
</div>  

<div class="new_member_box">
  <a href="javascript:void" class="question2">
    <h4>Church History</h4>
  </a>
</div>  

<div class="new_member_box">
  <a href="javascript:void" class="question3">
    <h4>Becoming a Member</h4>
  </a>
</div>  

<div class="new_member_box">
  <a href="javascript:void" class="question4">
    <h4>Pastor-in-Training</h4>
  </a>
</div> 
                            
<div class="clear" class="question"></div>
  <div  id="answer1">1</div> 
  <div  id="answer2">2</div> 
  <div  id="answer3">3</div> 
  <div  id="answer4">4</div>   
  <div class="new_member_box_display" id="question">
    Text will appear here when one of the tabs above is clicked
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfectly as far as I can see - it's updating the div content with no funny scrolling behaviours on my end

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution not touching HTML markup.

To prevent default behavior of click event, jQuery gives two options:

- [call `preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on event object
- explicetly `return false` from click handler - this is a shortcut for both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` simultaneously.

---

```
$('.question2').click(function(event){
    $('.new_member_box_display').html($('#answer2').html());
    event.preventDefault(); // first option
})

$('.question3').click(function(){
    $('.new_member_box_display').html($('#answer3').html());
    return false; // second option
})
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PZnSb/144/